Getting duplicate page inside when submitting a form
When I submit the form (i.e) placing a order I am getting a new duplicate page rendering inside my ship_now.html page . Tried changing logic in views which are

creating form in a new html file using block content

created new method for form submission instead of writing logic in same method.
but it doesn't help .
{% load static%}
   <html lang="en-GB">

 
 
 Ship Now | TrackItNow
         <a href="/">


          TrackItNow </div>
         </a>
     </div>

     <button type="button" class="jw-mobile-menu__button jw-mobile-toggle" aria-label="Toggle menu">
         <span class="jw-icon-burger"></span>
     </button>
 </div>
 <header class="header-wrap js-topbar-content-container js-fixed-header-container">
     <div class="header-wrap__inner">
         <div class="header">
             <div class="jw-header-logo">
                 <div class="jw-header jw-header-title-container jw-header-text jw-header-text-toggle" data-stylable="true">
                     <a id="jw-header-title" class="jw-header-title" href="/">
                         TrackItNow </a>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
         <nav class="menu jw-menu-copy">
             <ul id="jw-menu" class="jw-menu jw-menu-horizontal">
                 <li class="jw-menu-item">
                     <a class="jw-menu-link" href="/track_home/" data-page-link-id="24182718">
                         <span class="">
                             Home </span>
                     </a>
                 </li>
                 <li class="jw-menu-item jw-menu-is-active">
                     <a class="jw-menu-link js-active-menu-item" href="/ship_now/" data-page-link-id="24184780">
                         <span class="">
                             Ship Now </span>
                     </a>
                 </li>
                 <li class="jw-menu-item">
                     <a class="jw-menu-link" href="/order_list/" data-page-link-id="24184796">
                         <span class="">
                             Track order </span>
                     </a>
                 </li>
                 <li class="jw-menu-item">
                     <a class="jw-menu-link" href="/" data-page-link-id="24182760">
                         <span class="">
                             About Us </span>
                     </a>
                 </li>
                 <li class="jw-menu-item">
                     <a class="jw-menu-link" href="/contact" data-page-link-id="24182761">
                         <span class="">
                             Contact </span>
                     </a>
                 </li>

             </ul>


         </nav>
     </div>
 </header>
 <div id="jw-slideshow" class="jw-slideshow jw-slideshow-toggle jw-slideshow--height-ratio jw-slideshow--parallax jw-slideshow--parallax-effect banner-sm" data-pause="7000" data-autoplay="1" data-transition="horizontal" data-ratio="0.33">
     <div class="bx-wrapper">
         <div class="bx-viewport">
             <ul>
                 <li class="jw-slideshow-slide">
                     <div data-key="0" data-text="" data-subtext="" data-buttontext="" data-buttontarget="_self" data-backdrop="1" data-layout="no-text" style="background-position: 49% 52%; background-image: url(&#039;https://assets.jwwb.nl/assets/templates/concert-banner/countdown/slideshow.jpg?enable-io=true&amp;fit=bounds&amp;width=1920&amp;height=1920&#039;);" data-background-position-x="0.49" data-background-position-y="0.52" class="jw-slideshow-slide-content jw-slideshow-slide-content--display-cover jw-slideshow-slide-content--backdrop ">
                         <div class="jw-slideshow-slide-backdrop"></div>
                         <div class="bx-caption-wrapper jw-slideshow-slide-align-center">
                             <div class="bx-caption">
                                 <div class="jw-slideshow-title"></div>
                             </div>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                 </li>

             </ul>
         </div>
     </div>
     <!--    <div class="jw-slideshow__scroll-arrow">
         <i class="website-rendering-icon-down-open-big"></i>
     </div> -->
     <style>
         .jw-slideshow-slide-content {
             min-height: 33vh;
         }

         @media screen and (min-height: 1200px) {
             .jw-slideshow-slide-content {
                 min-height: 396px;
             }
         }
     </style>
 </div>

 <script nonce="e43b6b6e48ae8b8bda4c47be76cec015">
     JOUWWEB.templateConfig = {
         header: {
             selector: '.header-wrap__inner',
             mobileSelector: '.jw-mobile-menu',
             updatePusher: function(topHeight) {
                 var $sliderStyle = $('#sliderStyle');

                 if ($sliderStyle.length === 0) {
                     $sliderStyle = $('<style />')
                         .attr('id', 'sliderStyle')
                         .appendTo(document.body);
                 }

                 // Header height without mobile bar
                 var headerHeight = $('.header-wrap__inner').outerHeight();

                 var paddingTop = topHeight;
                 var paddingBottom = Math.min(headerHeight * (2 / 3), 60);
                 $sliderStyle.html(
                     '.jw-slideshow-slide-content {' +
                     '    padding-top: ' + paddingTop + 'px;' +
                     '    padding-bottom: ' + paddingBottom + 'px;' +
                     '}' +
                     '.bx-controls-direction {' +
                     '    margin-top: ' + ((paddingTop - paddingBottom) / 2) + 'px;' +
                     '}'
                 );

                 // make sure slider also gets correct height (because of the added padding)
                 $('.jw-slideshow-slide[aria-hidden=false]').each(function(index) {
                     var $this = $(this);
                     topHeight = $this.outerHeight() > topHeight ? $this.outerHeight() : topHeight;
                     $this.closest('.bx-viewport').css({
                         height: topHeight + 'px',
                     });
                 });

                 // If a page has a message-bar, offset the mobile nav.
                 const $messageBar = $('.message-bar');
                 if ($messageBar.length > 0) {
                     $('.js-mobile-menu, .jw-menu-clone').css('top', $messageBar.offset().top + $messageBar.outerHeight());
                 }
             },
         },
         mainContentOffset: function() {
             const $body = $('body');

             function measureAffixedHeaderHeight() {
                 const $headerWrap = $('.header-wrap');
                 const $headerWrapInner = $('.header-wrap__inner');

                 // Early return if header is already affixed
                 if ($body.hasClass('jw-is-header-affix')) {
                     return $headerWrap.height();
                 }

                 // Switch to affixed header (without transition)
                 $headerWrapInner.css('transition', 'none');
                 $body.addClass('jw-is-header-affix');

                 // Measure affixed header height
                 const headerHeight = $headerWrap.height();

                 // Switch back to unaffixed header (without transition)
                 $body.removeClass('jw-is-header-affix');
                 $headerWrap.height(); // force reflow
                 $headerWrapInner.css('transition', '');

                 return headerHeight;
             }

             const headerHeight = measureAffixedHeaderHeight();
             return $('.main-content').offset().top - ($body.hasClass('jw-menu-is-mobile') ? 0 : headerHeight);
         },
     };
 </script>
 <div class="main-content">

     <main class="block-content">
         <div data-section-name="content" class="jw-section jw-section-content jw-responsive">
             <div id="jw-element-404497730" data-jw-element-id="404497730" class="jw-tree-node jw-element jw-strip-root jw-tree-container">
                 <div id="jw-element-404497732" data-jw-element-id="404497732" class="jw-tree-node jw-element jw-strip jw-tree-container jw-strip--default jw-strip--style-color jw-strip--color-default jw-strip--padding-both jw-node-is-first-child jw-strip--primary jw-node-is-last-child">
                     <div class="jw-strip__content-container">
                         <div class="jw-strip__content jw-responsive">
                             <div id="jw-element-404502555" data-jw-element-id="404502555" class="jw-tree-node jw-element jw-contact-form jw-node-is-first-child jw-node-is-last-child">
                                 <!-- Display success message 
                                  {% if success_message %}
                                     <div class="alert alert-success">
                                         <p>{{ success_message }}</p>
                                     </div>
                                 {% endif %} -->
                                 {% block content %}
                                 {% endblock %}

                                 <form action="{% url 'ship_now' %}" method="POST" class="jw-form-container">
                                     {% csrf_token %}
                                     <div class="jw-element-form-group">
                                         <label for="pickup_location" class="jw-element-form-label">Pick location(eir code):</label>
                                         <div class="jw-element-form-content">
                                             <input type="text" name="pickup_location" required="required" id="pickup_location" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9]{3}[A-Za-z0-9]{2}[A-Za-z0-9]{2}" title="Please enter a valid Eircode (e.g., D12E9C7)" class="form-control&#x20;jw-element-form-input-text">
                                         </div>
                                     </div>
                                     <div class="jw-element-form-group">
                                         <label for="drop_location" class="jw-element-form-label">Drop location(eir code):</label>
                                         <div class="jw-element-form-content">
                                             <input type="text" name="drop_location" required="required" id="drop_location" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9]{3}[A-Za-z0-9]{2}[A-Za-z0-9]{2}" title="Please enter a valid Eircode (e.g., D12E9C7)" class="form-control&#x20;jw-element-form-input-text">
                                         </div>
                                     </div>

                                     <div class="hidden"><label for="jwFormQ32MAm_captcha" class="jw-element-form-label">Leave this field empty</label>
                                         <div class="jw-element-form-content">
                                             <input type="text" name="captcha" id="jwFormQ32MAm_captcha" class="form-control&#x20;jw-element-form-input-text" value="">
                                         </div>
                                     </div>
                                     <input type="hidden" name="csrf_3090566" id="jwFormsGo5U6_csrf_3090566" value="RlBTtPyYWSFKsGUq">
                                     <div class="jw-element-form-group">
                                         <button type="submit" class="jw-element-form-offset jw-btn jw-btn--size-small" name="submit">
                                             <div class="jw-btn-caption">Place order</div>
                                         </button>
                                     </div>

                                 </form>
                             </div>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
     </main>
 </div>

 <footer class="block-footer">
     <div data-section-name="footer" class="jw-section jw-section-footer jw-responsive">
         <div class="jw-strip jw-strip--default jw-strip--style-color jw-strip--primary jw-strip--color-default jw-strip--padding-both">
             <div class="jw-strip__content-container">
                 <div class="jw-strip__content jw-responsive">
                     <div id="jw-element-404457167" data-jw-element-id="404457167" class="jw-tree-node jw-element jw-simple-root jw-tree-container jw-tree-container--empty">
                     </div>
                     <div class="jw-credits clear">
                         <div class="jw-credits-owner">
                             <div id="jw-footer-text">
                                 <div class="jw-footer-text-content">
                                     &copy; 2024 TrackItNow </div>
                             </div>
                         </div>
                         <div class="jw-credits-right">
                             <div id="jw-credits-tool">

                             </div>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
 </footer>

 
 
     
 
 
 
     
     
     
     
     
     
     
     
     
     
     
     
     
     
     
     
     
     
     
     
     
     
     
     
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
     Unsafe.authorized();
 


Views.py :
I am loading ship_now page . After placing order I need to give a success message and reload ship_now page
def ship_now(request):


logger.info("\n\nUser placed1 order")
success_message = None
if request.method == 'POST':
    values_json = request.POST.get('values')
    values_data = json.loads(values_json)
    pickup_location = values_data.get('pickup_location')
    drop_location = values_data.get('drop_location')
    username = request.session.get('username', 'User')
    save_order_to_dynamodb(username, pickup_location, drop_location)
    success_message = "Order placed successfully!"
    return render(request, 'orders/ship_now.html', {'success_message': success_message})
return render(request, 'orders/ship_now.html', {'success_message': success_message})

enter image dese

I can't really see how you are submitting the form, but looking at what you have shared it looks like you might be using some javascript to do the post? Since you use the same html template for both the GET response and the POST response it is not surprising you get the full page back. Your view should return only the html that needs to be updated when handling the POST request.
